# Populate listview in second acitivity from firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-activity, layout

I know this question is asked many times but i could not get my head around it and i want to populate data from fire base to second activity and not first and i do not have a class but it is simple edit text so whenever people fill and click edit text the text will be saved on firebase and listview on second activity will be populate with firebase data
thank you and i do not want listview to be in main activity but i want to be in second activity which contain listview only.

Here is my code,

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText ed;
        Button b,b2;
        ArrayList<String>aded;
        String save,pus;
        // Write a message to the database
         FirebaseDatabase database ;
       DatabaseReference myRef ;
        DatabaseReference ref;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
            b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
            b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = database.getReference("message");
            ref=database.getReference("Oslan");



    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            save= ed.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(save)) {
                pus = ref.push().getKey();
                ref.child(pus).setValue(save);
                //myRef.setValue(save);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"put name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
           // databaseArtist=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("artist");

            aded=new ArrayList<>();
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           save= ed.getText().toString();
            aded.add(save);
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(save)) {
                pus = myRef.push().getKey();
                myRef.child(pus).setValue(save);
                //myRef.setValue(save);
                }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"put name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Listview.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("n",aded);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
        }


    }




    public class Listview extends AppCompatActivity {
     ListView listi;
        ArrayList<String>items;
     ArrayAdapter<String>adapt;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
            listi=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.l1);
            items=new ArrayList<>();
            Intent gett=getIntent();
            items=gett.getStringArrayListExtra("n");
            adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
            listi.setAdapter(adapt);
        }


    }
```

and list activity code is below thanks for help

```
    public class Listview extends AppCompatActivity {
     ListView listi;
        ArrayList<String>items;
     ArrayAdapter<String>adapt;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
            listi=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.l1);
            items=new ArrayList<>();
            Intent gett=getIntent();
            items=gett.getStringArrayListExtra("n");
            adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
            listi.setAdapter(adapt);
        }


    }
```

Comment: What you have done/tried so far?

Comment: i added my code thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to the database node in both your activities. Add this to both your activities:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("name_of_child");
```

Then in your first activity:

```
databaseReference.setValue(editText.getText().toString());
```

In your second activity:

```
String name;

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener)
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //get value from snapshot
        name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Log the error
    }
```

}

Comment: thanks krishna but i do not have class its simple edit text i do not know how to do it, please see my codes i added thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "I do not have class"

Comment: i do not have class like for example class of user where you store name of user, all i have is 2 activities and 2 layout associated with activities, in main activity i have button so when people type on edit text and click on the button, the button will add the edit text value to list view in secon activity and to firebase but what i need is when people click then the data will be saved on firebase that is easy part no problem but now i want any data on fire base will be populated on listview in the second activity

Comment: A separate class isn't necessary to retrieve data from the database. You can retrieve data using the getValue() method and provide String.class as the class to get string data. I've edited my answer to make it more specific to your current question.

Comment: Also try firebaseui, it might be of help to you

Comment: ok i did what you told me but for second activity .getvalue() is red so this is what i change to  String data = myRef.child("message").getKey(); now it show only messeage on the list view

Comment: if you know the answer the above is my code pleasae tell me specific what to do, thank you

Comment: hi again and thanks for getting back to me, i added your code and i add the string name to my array list but the app crashes here is my code items.add(name);

        adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
        listi.setAdapter(adapt);

Comment: i think adaptor has to be inside this constructor so when i add this line inside your code it will gives me red line   adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);  this is red line    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);

Comment: i changed this to getApplicationContext() the red line is gone but the app crashes

Comment: ok many many thanks Kirshna keshan , i have solved my problem by adding for loop to your code, ofcourse i didnt know but previously i watched another video but was using class, so i add the loop to your code and volla works perfect many thanks i will add my working code now, but i have another question, how to you remove a particular item from fire base thanks again

Answer (score -1):

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot dt:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         name = dt.getValue(String.class);
         items.add(name);
     } adapt=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
     listi.setAdapter(adapt);
 }
```

thank you Krishan has answered my question that i was strugling with

Comment: hello i added my new question here, i appreciate if you know  the answer  
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700447/when-click-on-listview-delete-it-and-delet-associated-data-with-it-in-firebase