# Android Firebase delete crash application on remove value

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete data from list view also from firebase.

```
 lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
            mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       DatabaseReference s =snapshot.getRef();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(String.valueOf(s)).removeValue();
                    }
                }
```

Application crashes on this line: `mDatabaseRef.child(String.valueOf(s)).removeValue();` 
I also use `setValue(null);`

[image: delete only this value]

Comment: please post the log also.

Comment: dont add log in it

Comment: when i add mDatabaseRef.child(somthing).removeValue(); App crash

Comment: But when i use simple mDatabaseRef.removeValue(); everything working fine but delete all value

Comment: maybe the value of  `s` is null, that's why its happening.

Comment: i check this value is get by debugger

Comment: w8 i am sharing with u

Comment: then you must delete it on the basis of the key which you want to delete like, mDatabaseRef.child("the key that you want to delete").removeValue();

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: https://booklive-a10ff.firebaseio.com/Hamza/-KxreDZ3efR4XZHTZ3Vz. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']' at

Comment: when i added key by hardcoded copy from firebase website then its work

Comment: butt i want this by programatically

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789) with more details on what you are trying to achieve and your logcat stack trace.

Comment: what you want to delete? a particular key in your reference or multiple keys in it? or what?

Comment: the below answer is correct, you can follow that up.

Comment: You want the key of the children, not the database reference. I suggest you use a debugger and log statements rather than letting the app crash

Answer (score 2):

To actually remove a child from a Firebase database, you need to pass to the `child()` method as an argument a `String` that represents a key from your database that is at a specific location.

`snapshot.getRef()` actually returns the entire reference of the location on which you have attached the listener.

`String.valueOf(s)` returns the `String` representation of your reference. In order to remove a value you need to use the actual String.

Let's take an example. You have the following path:

```
Firebase-root/users/uid/name
```

Where name has the value of `John`. In order to delete the `name` you need to use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users")
    .child("uid")
    .child("name")
    .removeValue();
```

and not this line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("users")
    .child("uid")
    .child("Firebase-root/users/uid/name")
    .removeValue();
```

Which is what you are trying to do with your code.

According with your new update, in order to delete that record, when you pushing that random key, you need first to store that key in a varable like this:

```
String key = yourRef.push().getKey(); //Store the pushed key
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Hamza")
    .child(key)
    .removeValue();
```

Comment: Upvoted for making sense of a diabolical question. Great answer too!

Comment: but in this how to get single value

Comment: In order to delete a record, you need to know which element you want to remove. There is no getting operation in here.

Comment: i added the picture in which i describe that which record i want to delete plz help

Comment: Use this line: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Hamza")
    .child("-KxrixE-JDgIB3E0FDF7")
    .removeValue();` Is your record deleted now?

Comment: That's why i told you to use a variable. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Can i help you with other informations?

Answer (score 0):

Its Crashing because you are not telling `fire-base` what to delete, to delete child node you have to tell `fire-base` that you want to delete that node do mention `.Child("hamza")` and then its child that you want to delete and if you want to delete `hamza` node then pass it `hamza` as key .get that value first and then remove it ,if you are using list view then get its id from `object` or `array` what ever you are passing .! and if you don't know about the key of that object all you have to do is query and then get that object key From  DataSnapshot using getKey() method like postsnapshot.getKey().Here `uid` is key of that child you want to delete.!

try to implement `model class` like this

```
class model {
private String name;
private String id;
private String url;

}

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Object obj = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
           function(objct.getkey());

        }
    });

private void function(String uid){

mdatabaseReference.child("hamza").orderByKey().equalTo(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        String key = postsnapshot.getKey();
        dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();

     }
}
```

Comment: Object uid = lv.getAdapter().getItem(position); is this uid u tell?

Comment: function(objct.getkey());
what is objct?

Comment: kindly post your adapter code as well.! are you using Object List in it or just simple array list .?

Comment: key is id of you object ..that is Kxrixe-jDg...!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageUpload> {
private Activity context;
private int resource;
private List<ImageUpload> listImage;


public ImageListAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<ImageUpload> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    listImage = objects;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(tvImageName);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    tvName.setText(listImage.get(position).getName());
    Glide.with(context).load(listImage.get(position).getUrl()).into(img);

    return v;

}
```

Comment: Home Screen Code.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700447/when-click-on-listview-delete-it-and-delete-associated-data-with-it-in-firebas